# Using ? (optionals) in Swift variables

Tags: ios, swift, optional-values

What exactly is the difference between a property definition in Swift of:

```
var window: UIWindow?
```

vs

```
var window: UIWindow
```

I've read it's basically an "optional" but I don't understand what it's for.

This is creating a class property called window right? so what's the need for the '?'

Comment: Read about it in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_428. It's a fundamental concept to Swift

Comment: Why would uiwindow in this case require an optional?

Comment: Also all the down votes on this question for no reason make me not want to help out around here as much as I try to.

Comment: I think in this case, a window might not be initialized/available. Thus, by defining it as an `optional`, if you call `window.addSubView()`, it will not unwrap and just return `nil`

Comment: A better example of an `optional` would be for a `delegate` property. This would allow you to call `delegate.protocolFunction()` without checking if `delegate` is `nil`. Please do go read about it in the docs though it does a great job explaining!

Comment: After answering and editing, realised that this has already been asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ? identifier means that the variable is *optional*, meaning its value can be nil. If you have a value in your code, declaring it as non-optional allows the compiler to check at build time if it has a chance to become nil.

You can check whether it is nil in an if statement:

```
var optionalName: String? = "John Appleseed"

if optionalName {
    // <-- here we know it's not nil, for sure!
}
```

Many methods that require a parameter to be non-nil will declare that they explicitly need a non-optional value. If you have an optional value, you can convert it into non-optional (for example, `UIWindow?` -> `UIWindow`) by *unwrapping* it. One of the primary methods for unwrapping is an `if let` statement:

```
var greeting = "Hello!"

// at this point in the code, optionalName could be nil

if let name = optionalName {
    // here, we've unwrapped it into name, which is not optional and can't be nil
    greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

See [The Swift Programming Language](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11), page 11 for a brief introduction, or page 46 for a more detailed description.

Answer (score 2):

`UIWindow?` means that the value may be absent. It's either an `UIWindow` instance or nothing.